# How to make second List<Elements> in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) android method?

Tags: android

Hello I'm beginner in android development. In this case I want to make second List but app crash and give me "Unfortunately,.... has stopped."

public class XMLPullParserActivity extends Activity {

```
ListView listView_Col1,listView_Col2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tab_ratingball);

 List<Item1_XML_elements> elements = null;
 //List<Item1_XML_elements> elements2 = null;
 XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();

 listView_Col1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.row2Col1);
 elements = parser.parseCol1(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xml_tab1));
 ArrayAdapter<Item1_XML_elements> adapter_Col1 = new ArrayAdapter<Item1_XML_elements>
                                                (this,R.layout.listing_row_rating, elements);
 listView_Col1.setAdapter(adapter_Col1);


 listView_Col2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.row2Col2);
 elements = parser.parseCol2(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xml_tab1));
 ArrayAdapter<Item1_XML_elements> adapter_Col2 = new ArrayAdapter<Item1_XML_elements>
                                                (this,R.layout.listing_row2_rating, elements);
 listView_Col2.setAdapter(adapter_Col2);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

I want to make two ListView with XMLParser and put them in two columns in TableLayout. Works but give me elements like these:

place          team

1               1

2               2

3               3

4               4

Name1          Name1

Name2          Name2

Name3          Name3

Name4          Name4

Comment: Take a look at the LogCat, copy and paste it in here and it will help us tell more of what is going on. Also post your xml for your activity. I will assume that it is because listView_Col2 is null, or something is up with adapter_Col2

Comment: Thanks! In LogCat doesn't have information. But before 5 seconds I found the problem and I made second  List<Item1_XML_elements> elements2 in class XMLPullParserHandler  and works prfectly. :)